# conditional operator in Velocity

Tags: velocity, ternary-operator

Is there a way to do ternary operators in Velocity?
This is what I'd like to do:

```
#set ($name = ($args.get(0) == "") ? "default" : $args.get(0))
```

Instead of chunky if-else

```
#if ($args.get(0) == "")
    #set ($name = "default")
#else
    #set ($name = $args.get(0))
#end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From experience and reading the [VTL Reference](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference.html) there is no way to do this. If you had lots of assignments like this maybe you could look at defining your own velocimacro to try and avoid repeating the if else.

For example, if the macro only prints a single string you could do the following:

```
#set ($name = "#condOpt($args.get(0), "default")")
```

The double quotes around the macro call are important as that means the RHS of the #set is parsed.

Comment: Is there a way to get a macro to act like a function? So that it will return a variable? So that I could do `#set ($name = condOpt($args.get(0), "default"))` If I made the macro do a check on `$args.get(0)` to see if it was empty or not..

Comment: If the macro only prints a single string you can set it to name. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yup. It was those double quotes around the macro call that caught me. Fixed and working now. Thanks (:

Answer (score 4):

I ended up doing as you said, Mark:

```
#macro(condOp $check, $default)
    #if ($check == "")
        $default
    #else
        $check
    #end
#end
```

And then I can call it like so:

```
#set ($name = "#condOp($args.get(0), 'default')")
```

Comment: You happened to be adding this just as I was editing my answer with the same example!!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, with Velocity 2.1+, you can provide [alternate reference values](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html#alternate-values):

```
${args[0]|'default'}
```